# end with query using match against in mysql

Tags: mysql, match-against

i want to retrieve those state that end with 'than' using match  agianst in mysql query.
i used the following query

```
SELECT * FROM yp WHERE MATCH (state) AGAINST ('*than' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

but it return and empty set of result.can anyone tell me what is the exact query?

Comment: `MATCH` works with full words inside text, not parts of the words. Use `LIKE` for this search, as Sakthi's answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM yp WHERE state LIKE '%than'
```

this query will return only those state are end up with 'than'. I think this may helps U..

Comment: i dont want to use like query coz it takes a full table scan

Comment: not if you use 'than%'. This will cause a full table scan '%than%'